# Reuse environment variables in tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is my `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "login",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "go run main.go login",
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "dbConnectionString": "host=localhost port=5431 user=user dbname=db password=pass sslmode=disable",
                    "spotifyClientID": "some-value",
                    "spotifyClientSecret": "another-value"
                }
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "getPlaylists",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "go run main.go getPlaylists",
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "dbConnectionString": "host=localhost port=5431 user=user dbname=db password=pass sslmode=disable",
                    "spotifyClientID": "some-value",
                    "spotifyClientSecret": "another-value"
                }
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't want to copy-paste the same environment variables in each task. May be there is a way to define all environment variables in the one place and then reuse them in each task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration works for me:

```
{ "version": "2.0.0",
  "options":{
    "env":{}
  },
  "tasks": [ ]
}
```